# I am writing a program which adds numbers inputed by the user and then outputting the total. With the total how can i output all the inputed numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I am the user and I input 1 then 3 then 7 then 5

I will get the output 16 but how can I also show the numbers I inputed i.e 1,3,7,5

Comment: Post your erroneous code and attempts

Comment: save your input one by one into list then finally print it :)

Comment: Can you show us the code that outputted `16`?

Comment: `inputs = [input('Enter Number:') for _ in range(4)]; print('+'.join(inputs), ,'=',sum(map(int,inputs))`

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store all inputs in a list and print them at the end.

```
inputs = []
#for each input
inputs.append(userinput)

for value in inputs:
    print(value)
```

if you want your numbers to be in the 1,3,7,5 format use

```
numbers = ",".join(str(value) for value in inputs) 
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable to store user inputs, Below is sample code for sum of two numbers
`n1 = int(input())`
`n2 = int(input())`
`s = n1 + n2`
`print(n1, n2, s)`

Answer (score 0):

MOST COMMON CODE:

Suppose you have this following code :

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = num1+num2
print(num3)
```

Now,you want num1 and num3 to be displayed,so u just have to do the following,thats it.

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = num1+num2
print(num3)
print(num1)
print(num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
>>> inputs = [input('Enter Number [%d]:' % (i+1)) for i in range(4)]
Enter Number [1]:1
Enter Number [2]:3
Enter Number [3]:5
Enter Number [4]:7

>>> print('{}={}'.format('+'.join(inputs), sum(map(int,inputs))))
1+3+5+7=16
```

Comment: The first line of code throws Type Error: TypeError: must be str, not int, change the code as this `inputs = [input('Enter Number [%d]:' %(i+1)) for i in range(4)]`

Comment: Missed the braces. Fixed Now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input('number: ').split()
print (a, sum(int(_) for _ in a))
```